# How to conditionally save the value of input tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to set value of input tag conditionally, I've two values for location state. One is coming from database and another one is coming from props. If user doesn't add his location, props value will be undefined. So, I wanted to do, something like if props value is present, then assign that value to input tag else keep location input tag as it is, i.e. value that is coming from database.

I tried with if else condition, If I don't give value of props, value of location tag is not remaining same, it is changing.

Anyone can please look into this?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./stationprofile.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { getCS, updateCS } from "../fetchingData/api_calls";

class StationProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      phone: "",
      open: "",
      close: "",
      cost: "",
      location: "",
      edit: true,
      error: "",
      success: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage
      .getItem("jwt")
    getCS(token).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState((state) => ({
        phone: data[0].cs_phone,
        open: data[0].cs_openat,
        close: data[0].cs_closeat,
        cost: data[0].cs_cost,
        location: data[0].cs_latitude + "," + data[0].cs_longitude,
      }))
    });
  }

  showSuccess = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-info"
      style={{ display: this.state.success ? "" : "none" }}
    >
      Profile Updated
    </div>
  );
  showError = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-danger"
      style={{ display: this.state.error ? "" : "none" }}
    >
      {this.state.error}
    </div>
  );
  
  handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ [name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  clickHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      edit: !this.state.edit
    });
    if (this.props.location === undefined){
      this.setState({ location: this.state.location })
      } else {this.setState({ location: this.props.location })};
      console.log(this.props.location);
      console.log(this.state.location);
  };

  clickSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

  //  this.setState((state) => ({ location: this.state.location }));

    const { phone, open, close, location, cost } = this.state;
    console.log(location)
    const token = localStorage
      .getItem("jwt")
    const lati = location[0];
    const long = location[1];
    updateCS({ phone, open, close, long, lati, cost }, token).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (
        data.length == 16 ||
        data == "YOU CAN ONLY ADD ONE CHARGING STATION." ||
        data == "Charging Station Already Exist" ||
        data == "YOU HAVE NO CHARGING STATION ADDED" ||
        data == "Charging Station DOESNT Exist" ||
        data == "Charging Station Already Exist" ||
        data == ""
      ) {
        this.setState({
          error: data,
        });
        this.showError();
      }  else {
        this.setState({
          phone: phone,
          open: open,
          close: close,
          location: location,
          cost: cost,
          success: true,
        });
        console.log("Station Updated");
      }
      // setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload() }, 2000);
    });
  };

  render() {
    const buttonText = this.state.edit ? (
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Edit your profile
      </Button>
    ) : (
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Back to profile
      </Button>
    );
    return (
      <div className="station__profile">
        <div className="station__profiles">
          <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>{buttonText}</button>

          {this.state.edit ? (
            <form className="station__container">
              <h3>Station Profile</h3>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled="true"
                  placeholder={this.state.phone}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Working Hours</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled="true"
                  placeholder={this.state.open + " till " + this.state.close}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Charges per Hour (in Rs)</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  disabled="true"
                  placeholder={this.state.cost}
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          ) : (
            <form>

              {this.showSuccess()}
              {this.showError()}

              <h3>Edit your station profile</h3>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Location</label>
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Location"
                  disabled="true"
                  value={this.state.location}
                />
                     <Button
              className="station__setlocation station__location"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
            >
              <Link to="/map"> Set Your Location Manually</Link>
            </Button>{" "}
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter phone number for station (optional)"
                  onChange={this.handleChange("phone")}
                  value={this.state.phone}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Working Hours</label>

                <div>
                  From:

                  <TextField
                    id="time"
                    ampm={false}
                    type="time"
                    defaultValue="00:00"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      step: 300, // 5 min
                    }}
                    onChange={this.handleChange("open")}
                    value={this.state.open}
                  />

                  To: 
                  
                  <TextField
                    id="time"
                    ampm={false}
                    type="time"
                    defaultValue="00:00"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      step: 300, // 5 min
                    }}
                    onChange={this.handleChange("close")}
                    value={this.state.close}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Charges per Hour (in Rs)</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter charges"
                  value={this.state.cost}
                  onChange={this.handleChange("cost")}
                />
              </div>

              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                onClick={this.clickSubmit}
              >
                Save changes
              </button>
            </form>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const msp = (state) => ({
  location: state.location,
});

export default connect(msp, null)(StationProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the location in props isn't strictly identical to `undefined`, your code will use it. If that's what's causing your error, does something like this work to choose the database's location?

```
const actualLocation = (this.props.location || this.state.location);
this.setState({ location: actualLocation });
```

Comment: Actually I got the error, value that I am getting from database isn't array. While value that is getting from props is array. So I changed state from location to "lat and long". This way I got access to props value as well as db values